# How to do google authentication without colab in your local pc?

Tags: python, authentication, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
*# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.*
*# This only needs to be done once per notebook.*
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file_id = 'xxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz' # URL id.
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
downloaded.GetContentFile('weight.pt')
```

I am using this in colab to download a weight file. But how do I do this in my local pc ? to use gdown I need the file in my gdrive to have "Anyone with link" permission granted which I can't do. so, what is the alternative to do google authentication in my local pc?

```
file_id = 'xxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz'     #enter your id here
!gdown --id {file_id}
```